# ¿Como puedo comprimir en tar archivos según su tamaño?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, script

Mi duda es que mi objetivo es comprimir por ejemplo los archivos de un directorio que pesen más de 100 MB. Sin embargo, no encuentro en el manual del comando tar una forma de hacerlo y no termino de verlo tampoco con el comando find e ir añadiendo los archivos uno a uno. Agradecería vuestra ayuda. Muchas gracias de antemano. Un saludo

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tar-command-linux-examples/ - seccion 8 ??

Comment: No, allí dice el tamaño del archivo tar ya comprimido. Lo que quiero hacer yo es seleccionar por tamaño los archivos a comprimir. Algo parecido a elegir los archivos txt con '*.txt' pero el equivalente en tamaño. @Excorpion

Comment: Que hay de esto - https://askubuntu.com/questions/907608/how-do-i-get-a-file-sizeoriginal-file-size-within-tar-gz-without-uncompress-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `find` para buscar los ficheros mayores de 100MB y `xargs` para montar los argumentos a pasarle a `tar`:

```sh
find . -type f -size +100M -print0 | xargs -0 tar -cvvjf ~/test.tar.bz2
```

Explicación:

- `find`:

  - `.`: Busca en el directorio actual y subdirectorios
  - `-type f`: Sólo ficheros (no directorios, ni pipes, ni devices, ...)
  - `-size +100M`: Con tamaño superior a 100MB
  - `-print0`: Separar los nombres de los ficheros con un carácter nulo `\0`
- `xargs`:

  - `-0`: Leer los argumentos separados por nulo `\0`
  - `tar -cvvjf ~/test.tar.bz2`: Comando `tar` al que añadir los fic heros encontrados. En este caso, como no lo has especificado, me tomo la libertad de:

    - `c`: Crear archivo
    - `vv`: *Verbose*
    - `j`: Usa `bzip2` para comprimir
    - `f ~/test.tar.bz2`: Archivo en el que guardar el resultado